# Word document is corrupted, weird characters shown on Notepad, can I recover it?

Tags: microsoft-word, data-recovery, microsoft-word-2016, file-recovery, file-corruption

After opening the file:
[image]

After clicking Yes
[image]

Content in Notepad
[image]

Content in Notepad (2)
[image]

Tried all four methods of [this part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/damaged-documents-in-word#troubleshooting-steps-to-try-if-the-damaged-document-does-not-open) of the troubleshooting guide from Microsoft. None worked.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: I recommend this software as I used it around 2010-2012 and it was much better than its competitors, although it can't recover 100% of corrupted word files. I can't comment on how whether competing software has improved after one decade. https://www.munsoft.com/EasyWordRecovery/

Comment: Modern Word documents are ZIP archives. You cannot open them in a text editor and expect to see something sensible.

Comment: How do you know that `sadfadsf` is actually a Word document?

Comment: @Mokubai I created the document inside the Word app a long time ago. Have been editing it in Word ever since. It also has a .docx. In File Explorer, it says Microsoft Word Document in the type section.

Comment: @DanielB While that's true it's also misleading. You can open `.docx` files in a zip editor like [WinRAR](https://www.rarlab.com/) to see what files it contains. It's free. Once you get the word file to behave as a zip file, you might be able to recover your text from it.

Comment: @alex1923 Where did you save this document? According to the error messages, I found [How to resolve...](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-resolve-the-problem-word-experienced-an-error-trying-to-open-the-file-when-opening-a-word-2007-2010-file-easy-fix-article-0903bb9b-d8e4-aabd-0364-f832d26ecff7) and [How to Fix...](https://www.yodot.com/blog/how-to-fix-word-experienced-an-error-trying-to-open-the-file), please check if they are helpful.

Comment: It's in the OneDrive folder.

Comment: @VikiJi I have tried the two fixes. They didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: @alex1923 Sorry for late. The strange thing is that I noticed that there is only the file name at the bottom of the second picture, not the full path address.
What if I save the file locally? In addition, can other computers be turned on normally?

Comment: The file is saved locally. Even in the web Word app, it doesn't open, so I think it also won't open in other computers.